# How does Google Tag Manager handle campaign data

Tags: e-commerce, google-tag-manager

This may be a really silly question, but I'm so fed up I have to ask.

If an external resource is directed to my website with campaign data, i.e.

```
utm_source=splodge&utm_medium=foobar&utm_campaign=santaclause
```

Do I need to capture this and pass it to Google Analytics through Google Tag Manager?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you deliberately override either the "location" field or  the campaign related fields in your Google Analytics tag configuration GTM will simply pass the values through to GA.

So while (to be pedantic) GTM itself does not "handle data" at all it does not interfere with the way configured tracking tools like GA handle data. No special action is necessary.

Comment: HI Eike, thanks for your reply. Some of the campaign sources for ecommerce transactions are not being reported. They're either not set or they're set to the payment gateway. Can you think of ways in which I can find out how to trouble shoot this?

I was thinking that I could capture the campaign data and send it directly but putting it into the dataLayer, is this possible, and would it be considered a good solution?

Comment: This might be an issue with GA rather than GTM - if you loose campaign info the first step would be to ad the payment gateway to the referral exclusion list (else the gateway will count as referral, the session of the visitor ends and a new session starts that has the payment gateway as traffic source).